# Where can I find NServicebus 2.1 source code?

Tags: nservicebus

I am looking for the NSB 2.1 source code. Does anyone have the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 2.1 , 2.5 is what you're after

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/v2.5

Comment: https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/v2.0 is the nearest to 2.1 that you'll get

Answer (score 0):

I have the *binaries* (no source, and only `NServiceBus.dll`, `NServiceBus.Core.dll`, and `NServiceBus.Host.exe`) for the 2.1 version that was available on the NServiceBus webpage for a short period of time last fall, but they're not entirely stable. If you really want them, contact me by email (just google my name).

Comment: I have the binaries. As you said the version is not stable and I want to fix a bug. That's why I need the source code.